# foreach the data of relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables `media_user` and `users`

media_user table like **[ id | user_id | media_id | link ]**

I need to bring all user from `media_user` by relationship, so I created relation in user model:

```
/**
* that users belong to the media_user table.
*/

public function media()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Social_Media','user_id','id');
}
```

And in the view, I did this

```
 @foreach ($user->media as $m)

   // my data

 @endforeach
```

I got the empty array when I dump the result as `dd($user->media)`

What is the problem pls?

Comment: This looks like a "many-to-many" relationship. Do you have a `media` table? What does `media_user.media_id` relate to? See https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many for full details.

Comment: @TimLewis I'm sorry! you right it was empty :( what stupid pro am I !

Comment: @TimLewis I have table media!

Comment: Yeah, then this is definitely a "many-to-many", meaning that `hasMany()` is the wrong relationship. You need to use `belongsToMany()` as referenced in the link I provided above. `media_user` is a pivot table, that links `users` and `media`

Comment: @TimLewis but when I create ( belongsToMany() )  it show me a big error I don't know what is it ! Now what should I do ? pls redirect me with thankful to right place cuz I hate my project if he has wrong concept of programming

Comment: Post the code you're using and the error you're getting... I can't help you debug with "when I create ( belongsToMany() ) it show me a big error"... Note, you should probably either open a new question, or remove the accepted answer below (as it doesn't really answer your actual issue). Probably asking a new question is best at this point.

Comment: @TimLewis I did it !!!!!! it works with belongsToMany!!! my error was cuz I used media_user model not media model! now everything is cool. big respect! you help  twice with this time, so never forgot your name! thanks Tim :)

Comment: No problem! Happy to help! And yeah, as a general rule, `pivot` tables (`media_user`) don't need a model. So in your case you would have a `User` and `Media` model, but not a `UserMedia` (or `Social_Media`) model. Using `attach()`, `detach()` and `sync()` will cover the basic logic, and `belongsToMany()` will access the records through your pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation looks fine, please check

1. there are some media items for the user with a correct foreign key.
2. there is an attribute in the user table called media.
3. there is no global scope.
4. the $user is a valid object and belongs to the ORM model

I suggest installing debug bar and view executed query on the media table